# Index of item in a list of a list in python

Tags: python-2.7, indexing, nested-lists

I got the following problem:
I'm writing a script for Ensight (a program for visualizing CFD computations) in python. 
The program Ensight gives me a list for the time values like:

```
print ensight.query(ensight.TIMEVALS)['timevalues']
[[0, 0.0], [1, 9.99e-07], [2, 1.99e-06], [3, 0.0003],etc.]
```

Where the first value in every list is the timestep and the second value the actual time at this timestep. Now I want to ask somehow for timestep '2' and want to know the corresponding second value of the list. Therefore if I could just find the index of the timestep I could easily have the corresponding time value.

EDIT\\
It solved it now like this:

```
time_values = ensight.query(ensight.TIMEVALS)['timevalues']
for start,sublist in enumerate(time_values):
    if step_start in sublist:
        index_begin = start
for end,sublist in enumerate(time_values):
    if step_stop in sublist:
        index_end = end
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
print ensight.query(ensight.TIMEVALS)['timevalues'][1][1]
```

That should print the 9.99e-07 as it is the second value in the second list included in your main list.

I'm just wondering why you have 3 opening and just 2 closing brackets. Is this a typo?

> [[ [..].. ]

If you have a list like  myList = [[0, 0.0], [1, 9.99e-07], [2, 1.99e-06], [3, 0.0003],etc.]
you can access the first nested list with myList[0] resulting in [0, 0.0]
To access the second value in that list you can use myList[0][1]

Comment: yes sorry, that was a typo! That is not what I want, because I'm generating a GUI where one can enter from which time step to which time step one wants to evaluate certain variables. And I want to prevent errors in case of the loaded CFD case file doesn't start with timestep = 0

Answer (score 1):

Set n to the required timestep value

```
>>> n=2
>>> print [list[1] for list in ensight.query(ensight.TIMEVALS)['timevalues'] if list[0]=n ]
```

this can also be extended in your case

```
>>> from=2
>>> to=100
>>> print [list[1] for list in ensight.query(ensight.TIMEVALS)['timevalues'] if (list[0]>from && list[0]<to)  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = ensight.query(ensight.TIMEVALS)['timevalues']

>>> print l
[[0, 0.0], [1, 9.99e-07], [2, 1.99e-06], [3, 0.0003]]

>>> _d = {int(ele[0]): ele[1] for ele in l}

>>> print _d[2]
1.99e-o6
```